# Server timeout error when using VerifyRenderingInServerForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I've got a gridview that I need to export data from.  Because of that, I'm using

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
}
```

I am also using an OnTextChanged event on a textbox on the asp side.

When I tab off the field, all of the OnTextChanged code runs, and then my form dies.  The buttons don't work.  I have to click back into the text field and then click directly onto my Submit button.

I put a break in the code-behind, and as I stepped through the code I got all the way to my VerifyRenderingInServerForm void.  It hit each control, and when it got to the end it threw this error at me:

```
> Unhandled exception at line 940, column 13 in
> http://localhost:1600/ScriptResource.axd?d=DT3YJR8QaqV61-
>   teuz0hgqSJ7kDD5t7Xub0FpxUhxWlplj4bYGQR_DPqpN98s92zwneBM3e_g-
>   QQioKQLgrgRPSHhAvY_dktK158uApJM1d6IbELIANMIxHN3LRQFaEt--dj1w2&t=ffffffffdc32f924
> 
> 0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error:
> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException: The server request timed out.
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: what does the code look like inside of VerifyRenderingInServerForm..? also have you looked at MSDN Documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.verifyrenderinginserverform(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's exactly as posted above.

Comment: well doesn't look like that code does anything sorry